# Android / Eclispe: how to run my app on device or emulator in release mode ? (if any...)

Tags: android, eclipse, release, release-mode, debug-mode

I am currently finishing the development of my Android app. I tested it extensively on both my Android phone and the emulator using my debug MD5 key and debugkeystore.

I generated a release MD5 key and keystore. I can create an apk file using "Export" in Eclipse (and then I sign with mu release keystore and alias). But, how can I run my app in release mode on my phone to be sure that everything is ok ? Is it possible ? Or perhaps it is not correct to speak about "running in release mode" and "running in debug mode" for Android ?

Thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think once you sign your apk with the release key, drop to a command prompt (if in windows), and issue the following command:

```
adb install <path_to_apk>
```

Where path_to_apk is the path to your signed apk.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move) link for more help with adb.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a signed apk file then,

```
Goto -> command prompt or Terminal -> reach at the your current sdk dir -> adb install <path_to_apk> .
```

And for [Android adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move).

Thnx.